# Combining two exe files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exe

Here's some background to my problem:

I have a project in Visual C++ 2006 and a project in in Visual C++ 2010 Express. Both compiles to form an exe file each. I cannot convert my 2006 project to 2010 because I get a lot of "unable to load project" errors. I also cannot port my 2010 project code to 2006 (I always get errors no matter what I try, something to do with libraries).

My final solution requires me to only have ONE executable. Is there anything I can do to achieve that? I've done some quick search on Google and found there to be exe joiners, but I've also heard that those things are often used to make malware.

For reference, I am working with "dummy" clients, and therefore want to simplify things on their end as much as possible. Thus, having them executing one exe is better than having them execute two. Also, I do not wish for their antivirus to go haywire because I used some program to join two exe together. What do?

Edit:

The two project files do different things. For example, the project in VS2006 one sets up a server, and the project in VS2010 one grabs info on the user's OS. The code for the "server", I think, has a lot of dependencies and for some reason cannot convert to Visual c++ 2010. The code for "grabbing" requires some newer libraries and compiling options, and would not work if I port to 2006.

Also I believe the exe merger I mentioned simply acts as a "container", in which it runs the two exe files one after the other.

Comment: An EXE merger can't merge programs with two distinctly different entry points. Which entry point would it execute?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't get the old c++ code and move that over to the newer project?

Comment: Fix the errors you get when you try to convert the Visual Studio "2006" (doesn't exist) project to 2010. Or better, to 2013.

Comment: Umm they do different things, and I want to combine their functionalities together into one exe. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only good solution is to port the oldest code (2006) to VS2010 (or both project to newer compilers), and compile a new executable from a fresh solution where you combine both projects as you wish.

As commented, merging two executables makes little sense in general (what is the entry point ? What about conflicting symbols ? What about the fact that different compilers and linkers generated those binaries ? etc...)